# Can I keep filefield value after post a form in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I have a form with a filefield, I submit the form to validate file content, however, I want to keep this form dirty, how can I achieve this ?
Im using Extjs 4.2

Comment: Give some detailed scenario?

Comment: I have a form which can upload a file to backend, before upload, I want to try validate firstly. So I submit the form after setting file to validate, and after press submit button, submit the form to upload

Comment: You can save the form values in the localstorage or save them in a coockie and reset the form after reloading the page....

Comment: I have the same problem, i found another way, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211812/file-upload-field-is-reset-when-submit-form/27903159#27903159

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, finally I save the value and this.setRawValue(this.filePath); after submit